# Should the checkbox indeterminate state be toggeled by a user

Tags: reset, checkbox

As the Indeterminate state of a checkbox can only be set programmatically I was wondering what the best approach would be for the following scenario.

**1. Starting with a GUI (checkbox and number input) controlled by a higher group.**
[image]


**2. On user interaction, the group values are overruled.**
[image]


**3. Removing the input values reverts back to the group values**
[image]

In the case of the checkbox, the intermediate state would be required but can't be achieved by the user through interaction with the checkbox. Is this even a way of doing so? Or am I better of implementing an extra reset button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest radio buttons.

```
( ) Same as group (Yes)
( ) Yes
( ) No
```

That pattern is also used in application settings, that can also be set on system level, like language or theme.

Here’s the example from Figma:

[image: A theme input with an expanded menu with three options: Light, Dark, System theme. The last option is checked]

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see I would fix the following:

- After incorrect data entry, do not cross out the explanation below. Make them red or add a message about what the problem is.
- Add reset button. The check box seems to me not the best component for these purposes.

If I still haven't answered your question, please send more description.